# How to get Authorizer Id from Resource Id in AWS SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sdk, lambda-authorizer

I am using Java ApiGatewayClient and using it to return all resources by calling:

`var res = apiGatewayClient.getResources(getResourcesRequest);`

Now, according to sdk I should be able to get Authorizer id by `res.items().get(0).resourceMethods().get("POST").authorizerId();`

But I always recieve null value here, even though I cross checked from AWS, and AuthId exists and is in place.

I got all the resources and in them not even one had authId value other than null.

Is this is a bug from AWS, or am I doing something wrong here?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Sample Response:

```
{
    "path": "/dummy/v1",
    "id": "x977w7",
    "resourceMethods": {
        "POST": {
             "authorizerId": null,
             "httpMethod": null,
             "operationName": null
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Java doesn't have an ApiGatewayClient, the AWS SDK has. But the ApiGatewayClient is used for accessing/modyfing the API Gateway. What do you want? Do you want to authorise the lambda? Or modify the api gateway to have a authoriser attached?

Comment: @Augunrik I want get authorizer Id from resource Id(Req 1) to be able to get lambda Function name from authorizer uri(Req 2) from where I will update lambda configuration(Req 3). Now Req 2 and 3 are tested and working fine. But I am not getting authorizer Id with ApiGatewayClient. It is being returned as null.

Comment: This still doesn't clear it up for me. Is it IaC Code you are writing or Lambda Code that gets executed by request? ApiGateway can only report an AuthoriserId, if one has been assigned to the method. Has this been done?

Comment: @Augunrik I am building up a pipeline with series of requests. Authorizer Id is assigned. Also, I tried hitting the same request from node server through javascript aws sdk using same credentials and request params. And I successfully got AuthorizerIds.

Comment: @Augunrik also I reported this as a bug. Maybe you could get a better idea, I have added some extra information on the matter here. [Github Issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/2939)